# How to sort a string in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

i.e. from `"cba"` to `"abc"`. Given that it seems the `lang.string` module lacks sorting support and the `array:sort()` function doesn't accept strings? Currently, my workaround involves converting the string to a `string:Char[]` and then using `arrays:sort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to convert the string to `string:Char[]` and do it.

```
string str = "cdba";
string:Char[] arr = [];
foreach string:Char ch in str {
    arr.push(ch);
}
string sorted = string:'join("",...arr.sort());
```

Alternatively, you could probably use a query expression.

```
string str = "cdba";
string sorted = from string char in str order by char select char;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina string library has a method named `toCodePointInts` which represents an array of code points for the corresponding string. Since this returns an array, we can sort it and construct the string from the sorted code points using `fromCodePointInts`, which in summary sorts the given string.

```
string str = "cdba"    
string sortedStr = check string:fromCodePointInts(str.toCodePointInts().sort());
```

Note that the above approach works only if each code point corresponds to a single Unicode character. If a character consists of multiple code points, then the sorting would be inconsistent.